# sort and uniq a file with a specific column and only keep 1st value from given file

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

I have sample file

```
$ cat a.csv
a,1,c
b,1,d
d,3,a
s,2,c
a,3,s
```

Required

```
a,1,c
s,2,c
a,3,s
```

It must remove all other value after uniq but only keep 1st value

sort and uniq

```
a,1,c
s,2,c
a,3,s
```

I try `sort -k2 -n a.csv` but gave me this result

```
a,1,c
a,3,s
b,1,d
d,3,a
s,2,c
```

when I try `sort -k2 -n a.csv  | uniq -d` I got blank result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sort -t, -u -k2,2 a.csv 
a,1,c
s,2,c
d,3,a
```

- `-t,` to specify `,` as delimiter
- `-u` to get only unique entries
- `-k2,2` use second column as criteria for sorting

Comment: The output is not exactly as "Required" (see the last line of output). I'm not sure if that really matters or if OP just wanted one of each value on the second field.

Comment: @WDC can you explain what is the sorting criteria then? I think you want `sort a.csv | sort -t, -u -k2,2` but not sure

Comment: @Sundeep, to be honest, I am using your code in my script... because after sort whoever deletes doest matter, 1st or last.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{if(!($2 in a)||$0<a[$2])a[$2]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file
```

Output (in awk default order):

```
a,1,c
s,2,c
a,3,s
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F, '                                  # fields comma-separated
{
    if(!($2 in a) || $0<a[$2])               # if $2 unseen or record < stored record
        a[$2]=$0                             # store it to a hash
}
END {                                        # after processing the file
    # PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"  # sort output on $2 if using GNU awk
    for(i in a)                              # iterate all stored instances in a 
        print a[i]                           # and output
}' file
```

The output order will be awk default ie. may appear random. If you want the output sorted, you need to use `sort` or if you are using GNU awk, uncomment the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"` in the explained version (or add the line to the one-liner).